# PHP store simple variable

Tags: php, store

I have a very simple web synchronization PHP I want to build which basically returns a unique number between 0-20 every time it is loaded. simple, right?

Well in order to do this, I need to store the last number that was sent.

I know of two ways to do this, one being storing the number in a file on the server and going through having to rewrite, write, etc over and over again, or, even worse, using MySQL to store one integer in one row in a one column table.... both seem overcomplicated to me.

So this takes me to a question, is there a way to store a simple integer without using MySQL or the file system?

P.S. I seem to have forgotten to mention this, but I need to store the information across all clients, not just per-client. Anything relating to cookies will not work

Comment: Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: Depending on the rest of the application storing the variable inside of a mysql table or into a file on the server are your best bets. The former being the better option if you already have a database and you aren't just creating one to track this one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't personally used this but it seems that this could be an alternative solution as well: [APC Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php)

Answer (score 5):

You can store it in the session

Put `session_start();` at the top of each page.
Access `$_SESSION['number']`. It will persist across pages for that user.

Comment: In that case, use redis.io, MySQL, or a file.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen So include this **important information** in your **question**!

Comment: @Nadav S. very sorry, I have a migraine at this moment, and I could have sworn I mentioned this in my question

Answer (score 1):

If the data has to be:

- **Unified** for all users
- **Must not** include **cookies**/ **sessions**
- **Has to be simple** - which means that MySQL is not a good solution

Then the best and simplest solution is by using a **file**.

1. **Create** a file, yourself. A **TXT** file seems to work great.
2. **Write** the initial integer in it.
3. **Store** the integer once a user is updated it / whatever he does:

   `$file = fopen('data.txt','w')`, `fwrite($file,2)`
4. And in case you have to check the last data, use

   `$last_int = fread($file)`